# jQuery - Cycle backwards and forwards through array on click.

Tags: jquery

I would like the be able to cycle backwards and forward through multiple arrays, I've only been able to make it cycle forward, but not backwards.

Here is where I am so far. (You'll notice the down arrow button is not working)

Any insight would be welcomed!

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq4ddx/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<button class="btn-down">v</button>
    CUSTOM HOURS
<button class="btn-up">^</button>
<p class="price-select">1200</p>
<p class="hours-select">3</p>
<p class="photos-select">200-400+</p>
<p class="postproduction-select">15</p>
</div>
<div class="weekend-notice">Note: Weekend bookings available at a minimum of 5 hours.</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
//FOR CUSTOM HOURS BUTTON
var price = ["1400", "1600", "1800", "2000", "2200", "1200"];
var hours = ["4", "5", "6", "7", "10", "3"];
var photos = ["400-600+", "600-800+", "800-1000+", "1000-1200+", "1200-1400+", "200-400+"];
var editing = ["17", "19", "22", "25", "30", "15"];

var i = 0;
$(".btn-up").on('click', function() {
$(".price-select").hide().html(price[i]).fadeIn(300);
$(".hours-select").hide().html(hours[i]).fadeIn(300);
$(".photos-select").hide().html(photos[i]).fadeIn(300);
$(".postproduction-select").hide().html(editing[i]).fadeIn(300);
  i++;
  i = i % 6;

var checkHours = parseInt($('.hours-select').text());
var weekendNotice = $('.weekend-notice');
var hoursNotice = $('.morehours-notice');

if(checkHours <= 4){
    weekendNotice.fadeIn(500);
}else{
    weekendNotice.fadeOut(500);
};

});
```

Comment: Why increment `i` *after* reading the values from the arrays? It's not as if you know which button is going to be clicked next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to calculate the index for the "up" and "down" actions in one line, and coding this can be made easier by first setting data values of `1` and `-1` on the up/down buttons.

It is also better practice to initialise via the script rather than hard-code in HTML.

```
//FOR CUSTOM HOURS BUTTON
var price = ["1400", "1600", "1800", "2000", "2200", "1200"];
var hours = ["4", "5", "6", "7", "10", "3"];
var photos = ["400-600+", "600-800+", "800-1000+", "1000-1200+", "1200-1400+", "200-400+"];
var editing = ["17", "19", "22", "25", "30", "15"];

var i = 0,
    n = hours.length; // 6

$(".btn-up").data('dir', 1);
$(".btn-down").data('dir', -1);

$(".btn-up, .btn-down").on('click', function() {
    // ***** this line handles both directions *****
    i = (i + $(this).data('dir') + n) % n;
    // ***** ********************************* *****
    $(".price-select").hide().html(price[i]).fadeIn(300);
    $(".hours-select").hide().html(hours[i]).fadeIn(300);
    $(".photos-select").hide().html(photos[i]).fadeIn(300);
    $(".postproduction-select").hide().html(editing[i]).fadeIn(300);
    if(parseInt(hours[i]) <= 4) {
        $('.weekend-notice').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $('.weekend-notice').fadeOut(500);
    };
});

$(".btn-down").trigger('click'); //initialize
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p6h2bpeh/)**

Comment: This is by far the best option, awesome job. I plan to study this code closely, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".btn-down").on('click', function() {
  $(".price-select").hide().html(price[i]).fadeIn(300);
  $(".hours-select").hide().html(hours[i]).fadeIn(300);
  $(".photos-select").hide().html(photos[i]).fadeIn(300);
  $(".postproduction-select").hide().html(editing[i]).fadeIn(300);
  if(i == 0) {
      i = 5
  } else {
      i--;
  }

  var checkHours = parseInt($('.hours-select').text());
  var weekendNotice = $('.weekend-notice');
  var hoursNotice = $('.morehours-notice');

  if(checkHours <= 4){
    weekendNotice.fadeIn(500);
  }else{
    weekendNotice.fadeOut(500);
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks Adnan Y. Problem though, when I click on the arrows, it seems to cycle in the wrong direction on the first click, and then start cycling in the right direction upon the second click.

http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq4ddx/8/

Comment: It's due the modulo that you are doing in the up function. Instead use similar logic where you check if(i == 5){ i=0 }else{ i++; }

Answer (score 1):

Start with `index = -1` and iterate forward like this

`i = (i+1) % (price.length);` *(I used one of the arrays as a reference for length)*

and backward like this

```
if (i <= 0) {
    i = price.length - 1;
} else {
    --i;
}
```

I think it is important where you place them.

```
var i = -1;
$(".btn-up").on('click', function () {
    i = (i+1) % (price.length);
    $(".price-select").hide().html(price[i]).fadeIn(300);
    $(".hours-select").hide().html(hours[i]).fadeIn(300);
    $(".photos-select").hide().html(photos[i]).fadeIn(300);
    $(".postproduction-select").hide().html(editing[i]).fadeIn(300);

    var checkHours = parseInt($('.hours-select').text());
    var weekendNotice = $('.weekend-notice');
    var hoursNotice = $('.morehours-notice');

    if (checkHours <= 4) {
        weekendNotice.fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        weekendNotice.fadeOut(500);
    };

});
$(".btn-down").on('click', function () {
    if (i <= 0) {
        i = price.length - 1;
    } else {
        --i;
    }
    $(".price-select").hide().html(price[i]).fadeIn(300);
    $(".hours-select").hide().html(hours[i]).fadeIn(300);
    $(".photos-select").hide().html(photos[i]).fadeIn(300);
    $(".postproduction-select").hide().html(editing[i]).fadeIn(300);

    var checkHours = parseInt($('.hours-select').text());
    var weekendNotice = $('.weekend-notice');
    var hoursNotice = $('.morehours-notice');

    if (checkHours <= 4) {
        weekendNotice.fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        weekendNotice.fadeOut(500);
    };

});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/4pbq4ddx/10/**

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `button` selector , single `click` handler increment , decrement `i` based on `e.target` of `event`

```js
// FOR CUSTOM HOURS BUTTON
var price = ["1400", "1600", "1800", "2000", "2200", "1200"];
var hours = ["4", "5", "6", "7", "10", "3"];
var photos = ["400-600+", "600-800+", "800-1000+"
              , "1000-1200+", "1200-1400+", "200-400+"];
var editing = ["17", "19", "22", "25", "30", "15"];

var i = price.length - 1;
$("button").on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is(".btn-up")) {
    i = i === price.length - 1 ? 0 : ++i;
  } else {
    if ($(e.target).is(".btn-down")) {
      i = i > 0 ? --i : price.length - 1;
    };
  };
  $(".price-select").hide().html(price[i]).fadeIn(300);
  $(".hours-select").hide().html(hours[i]).fadeIn(300);
  $(".photos-select").hide().html(photos[i]).fadeIn(300);
  $(".postproduction-select").hide().html(editing[i]).fadeIn(300);

  var checkHours = parseInt($('.hours-select').text());
  var weekendNotice = $('.weekend-notice');
  var hoursNotice = $('.morehours-notice');

  if (checkHours <= 4) {
    weekendNotice.fadeIn(500);
  } else {
    weekendNotice.fadeOut(500);
  };

});
```

```css
p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn-down">v</button>CUSTOM HOURS
  <button class="btn-up">^</button>
  <p class="price-select">1200</p>
  <p class="hours-select">3</p>
  <p class="photos-select">200-400+</p>
  <p class="postproduction-select">15</p>
</div>
<div class="weekend-notice">Note: Weekend bookings available at a minimum of 5 hours.</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq4ddx/14/

Comment: Thanks for the help! Wanted to bring to your attention that pushing the down button initially doesn't scroll backwards. I'm not sure if this is intentional, but it isn't the desired effect. I played around with it a bit and couldn't figure out how to make is scroll back if clicked first.